# Remove Filepath in GridFS

Tags: c#, mongodb, gridfs

I am using the official c# driver for MongoDB and when I upload a file, the metadata contains the filename WITH the path, which is not what I would like:

```
var gfs = new MongoGridFS(database);
var gfsi = gfs.Upload("c:\a.pdf");
```

The resulting metadata is:

```
"_id" ...
"filename" : "c:\\a.pdf",
...
```

Is it possible to remove the path oder just write the filename?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MongoGridFS class exposes multiple overloads for the Upload and Download methods, including one in which you can specify differing remote/local paths.

e.g.

```
var gfs = new MongoGridFS
gfs.Upload(@"c:\a.pdf", "a.pdf");
gfs.Download(@"c:\b.pdf", "a.pdf");
```

The filename for the GridFS object always refers to the remote filename you set here and the original filename would be otherwise lost.